# ¿Como configurar Apache para python?

Tags: python

He estado intentando configurar apache en mi PC para probar mis aplicaciones web con Python. Intenté instalar mod_wsgi, desde la carpeta de apache24 y me sale esto, con un error al final:

```
C:\Apache24>pip install mod_wsgi
Collecting mod_wsgi
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/69/5139588686eb40053f8355eba1fe18a8bee94dc3efc4e36720c73e07471a/mod_wsgi-4.6.5.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: mod-wsgi
  Running setup.py install for mod-wsgi ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\cob19\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\cob19\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gaw7te9h\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\cob19\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-570vos8x\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    c:\users\cob19\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi
    copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
    copying src\server\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management
    copying src\server\management\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    copying src\server\management\commands\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\docs
    copying docs\_build\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\docs
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\images
    copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\mod_wsgi\images
    running build_ext
    building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\cob19\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\cob19\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gaw7te9h\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\cob19\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-570vos8x\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\cob19\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gaw7te9h\mod-wsgi\
```

Ya he instalado visual Studio c++ las nuevas versiones, he reiniciado la computadora y nada. Sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: ¿Has intentado instalar Microsoft Build Tools 2015 y aún así te sigue saliendo el error? https://www.microsoft.com/es-mx/download/details.aspx?id=48159  Puede que necesites instalar alguna otra dependencia. Te puede servir echar un vistazo a https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/409173/error-microsoft-visual-c-140-is-required.html

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Resolví el problema con esto:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541801/microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-get-it-with-microsoft-visual-c-build-t  Más o menos es lo que había hecho varias veces pero cuando marqué otras opciones de instalación como sugiere este señor, entonces funiono bien.